# r data table issues with dynamic names in i

Tags: r, data.table

I construct a vector of columns (`dt.commod`) that have some values I want to change (`c("-", "...", "0 0")`) to 0. I thought some variation on the following code would work (`prodYears[j]`, `get(prodYears[j])`) but none of them do.

```
 dt.commod <- data.table::as.data.table(openxlsx::read.xlsx(filePath, colNames = TRUE, cols = NULL,
                                                             sheet = commodName))
  prodYears <- c("prod_qty_2011", "prod_qty_2012",  "prod_qty_2013")
  for (j in 1:length(prodYears)) {
    dt.commod[get(prodYears[j]) %in% c("-", "...", "0 0"), prodYears[j] := "0" ]
  }
```

If instead I run the column names directly, as in

```
dt.commod[prod_qty_2011 %in% c("-", "...", "0 0"), prod_qty_2011 := "0"]
```

it does what it's supposed to.

Comment: Odd. Might help to see a reproducible example. I might do it with `for (col in cols) DT[.(vals), on=col, (col) := "0" ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more browsing on related questions, I added

```
data.table::setkeyv(dt.commod, prodYears)
```

just before the `for` loop. I don't understand why this works but it does.